# How to make arc in android

Tags: android, xml

i just want to know how to make this half circle

[image]

but my output is like this

[image]

this is my xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
android:topRightRadius="20dp"
 />
<stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
    />
<padding
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
     />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#900021df"/>
        <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="60dp"/>
       <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="60dp"
        android:topRightRadius="60dp"/>
    </shape>
```

Create one semicircle.xml under drawable folder.
 Add above code to your XML.
 
Please let me know whether it's working or not...

Output will look like

[image]

**Edit:**

Just a little bit change in the above code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

   <size
       android:width="120dp"
       android:height="60dp"/>
   <corners
       android:topLeftRadius="60dp"
       android:topRightRadius="60dp"/>
   <stroke
      android:color="#919191"
      android:width="1dp"
      />

</shape>
```

Output:
[image]

Not Satisfied? Why don't you create it on canvas using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/ArcShape.html) or use [this](https://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) for converting SVG into XML code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code contains stroke

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#90000000" />
            <size
                android:width="120dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="60dp"
                android:topRightRadius="60dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#90DF1E1E" />
            <size
                android:width="120dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="60dp"
                android:topRightRadius="60dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval"
       android:useLevel="false" >
   <solid android:color="#006AC5" />
   <size
    android:height="50dp"
    android:width="50dp" />
</shape>
```

and this is a example:

[image]

I hope it can help your problem!